# What EOS RPC Libraries are available?

Tags: rpc

I know that EOS provides a [first-party JavaScript RPC library](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs) for interacting with the EOS blockchain.  Are their libraries available for other languages (e.g. Java, Python, Obj-C, etc)?

Comment: Perfect timing for this question. Someone asked about .net on Telegram.

Answer (score 5):

We built the Elixir one: https://hex.pm/packages/eosrpc

As our project depends on it, we will always keep it updated! Feel free to create issues to report bug, new ideas and any discussion! :)

Comment: What language is this library for?

Comment: I said above: elixir ;)

Answer (score 5):

There's also a Swift library: https://github.com/ProChain/SwiftyEOS

And Go: https://github.com/eoscanada/eos-go

Comment: Also https://github.com/memtrip/eos-swift

Answer (score 2):

A java sdk with eos-rpc: https://github.com/adyliu/jeos

local signature support like this:

- [Transfer EOS with java](https://gist.github.com/adyliu/b35ec8551c05f82a1d7307395d4910da)
- [Create account with java](https://gist.github.com/adyliu/6d30650cf2f6d0a703d5b547db484d31)
- [Create EOS Key with java without RPC](https://gist.github.com/adyliu/63d93895d07678d3d80a52dfbcb18976)
- [Sign transaction offline](https://gist.github.com/adyliu/492503b94d0306371298f24e15481da4)

Comment: Can Transfer Eos example be used to invoke any smart contract by changing the account,action & data?

Answer (score 0):

We have developed a Java RPC library for interacting with EOS:  https://github.com/TopiaCoin/EOSRPCAdapter-Java

Answer (score 0):

A kotlin SDK: https://github.com/memtrip/eos-jvm

- EOS nodeos RPC API
- Local transaction signing
- Annotation preprocessor to generate abi writer boilerplate
- Keypairs
- Easily compose transaction actions for:

  - [CreateAccount](https://github.com/memtrip/eos-jvm/blob/master/eos-chain-actions/src/test/kotlin/com/memtrip/eos/chain/actions/transaction/newaccount.kt)
  - [BuyRam](https://github.com/memtrip/eos-jvm/blob/master/eos-chain-actions/src/test/kotlin/com/memtrip/eos/chain/actions/transaction/buyram.kt)
  - [SellRam](https://github.com/memtrip/eos-jvm/blob/master/eos-chain-actions/src/test/kotlin/com/memtrip/eos/chain/actions/transaction/sellram.kt)
  - [DelegateBandwidth](https://github.com/memtrip/eos-jvm/blob/master/eos-chain-actions/src/test/kotlin/com/memtrip/eos/chain/actions/transaction/delegatebw.kt)
  - [UndelegateBandwidth](https://github.com/memtrip/eos-jvm/blob/master/eos-chain-actions/src/test/kotlin/com/memtrip/eos/chain/actions/transaction/undelegatebw.kt)
  - [Transfer](https://github.com/memtrip/eos-jvm/blob/master/eos-chain-actions/src/test/kotlin/com/memtrip/eos/chain/actions/transaction/transfer.kt)
  - [Vote](https://github.com/memtrip/eos-jvm/blob/master/eos-chain-actions/src/test/kotlin/com/memtrip/eos/chain/actions/transaction/vote.kt)